# One word for a person who sees a message but doesn't reply?

Tags: single-word-requests, internet, social-media

There are some people who will receive a message, see it, but don't reply to it. Is there a word for such people?

Comment: Non espondent /  https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nonrespondent

Comment: sometimes they’re called lurkers.

Comment: I've upticked @Xanne here but wanted to opine that Lurkers becomes slang when applied in this way, I hope it does make its way into the lexicon coz it feels so right ( unlike Coz!).

Comment: Do you mean someone who does not reply to a message intended for them personally, or one who reads a conversation among others without contributing to it?  The latter is often called a *lurker*, but I don't know a noun for the former.

Answer (score -2):

You might consider [acknowledger](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/acknowledger)

> A person who acknowledges or recognizes someone or something.

Such as the person who signs acknowledgement of receipt for a parcel.

This opens the door to an interesting **unacknowledger** from [unacknowledged](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/unacknowledged) for the kind of person who first opens a message, marking it read, then marks it unread.

Comment: Newish user; I down voted you , got the "please consider a comment" tried to Undownvote you and failed 

Comment: @user356866 I think there is a "grace period" for changing votes and flags. Possibly you exceeded it. Why do you want to retract your DV? Can I assist you in some way? I already up-voted to offset negative voting.